# Are Riemann integrals necessarily convergent sums?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

For example, does the Riemann sum of $\sum_2^n$ $\frac{1}{k} \frac{1}{n}$ converge to the integral $\int_2^n \frac{1}{x}dx$?

Does the 1/n factor help the sum of 1/k converge?  It doesn't look obvious, just from using the definitions.  Is there a comparison we can make with the p-series?

Or perhaps Riemann integrals aren't necessarily convergent infinite sums?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

From this picture (taken from the [Wikipedia article on Harmonic series (mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Integral_test)) we can see that

$$\int_2^n \frac 1x\,dx<\sum_{k=2}^n \frac 1k<\int_1^n \frac 1x\,dx$$

So

$$\ln n-\ln 2<\sum_{k=2}^n \frac 1k<\ln n$$
$$\frac 1n(\ln n-\ln 2)<\frac 1n\left(\sum_{k=2}^n \frac 1k\right)<\frac 1n\ln n$$
$$\frac{\ln n}n-\frac{\ln 2}n<\sum_{k=2}^n \frac 1k\frac 1n<\frac{\ln n}n$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln n}n-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln 2}n \le
 \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=2}^n \frac 1k\frac 1n \le
 \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln n}n$$
$$0-0\le \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=2}^n \frac 1k\frac 1n \le 0$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=2}^n \frac 1k\frac 1n=0$$

So the "Riemann sum" you give converges to zero, while the other expression $\int_2^n \frac 1x\,dx=\ln n-\ln 2$ goes off to $+\infty$.

So **your given sum does not converge to your given integral.**

The problem is that your supposed "Riemann sum" is not actually a Riemann sum. One of the actual Riemann sums for your integral $\int_2^n \frac 1x\,dx$ is

$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{n-2}m\frac{1}{2+\frac{n-2}mk}$$

which you can see is very different from your sum. One difference is the extra variable $m$ in the actual Riemann sum. The variable that varies to infinity in the Riemann sum is not the upper limit of the integral, it is another variable altogether.

**Does the $\frac 1n$ factor help the sum of $\frac 1k$ to converge? Yes, it does**, just as $\ln n$ does not converge but $\frac{\ln n}n$ does converge.

**I do not see any comparison with the p-series.**

**Riemann integrals *are* convergent sums**, but they are a variety of *particular* infinite sums. It is easy to get confused as to which particular infinite sums they are.

Comment: Hi @RoryDaulton, I read your answer earlier today and wanted to think about it a bit before responding.  I just read it again and I agree with you -- thanks so much for your time and for your cautions.  My gut feeling last night was that I was blindly thinking of my "Riemann sums" that I had written down on paper as certain Riemann integrals that it must be, **simply because**, the factor I put into the sum, which I considered the mesh size of partition, goes to zero, i.e., mesh(p) = 1/n goes to zero, so I thought my sum "must" converge to the integration of (1/x) dx.

Comment: I knew something wasn't quite correct.  Thanks for showing that the summation must be zero, by the Squeeze Theorem - that's really pretty.  Can I ask you a quick follow-up question?

Comment: If I back up just a bit, and revisit the definitions, then do you agree that if I start with the summation of $f(x_k^*)$$\frac{1}{n}$, sum from k = 1 to n, and then let n go to infinity, then this limit of Riemann sums, **if it exists**, as you had warned (and can be checked by all of the usual series convergence tests) is the Riemann integral of f(x)dx from **0 to 1**,

Comment: since the total interval length in the sum was n(1/n) = 1 (letting n go to infinity refines the partition of the interval and of course does not change its length that we started with.)  What do you think?  I'll learn to be suspicious from now on about my "Riemann sums".  Thanks, @RoryDaulton.